# QPixmap(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have this code that take image and detect edges but it give me this error

```
TypeError: QPixmap(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
```

```
def detect_Image(self):
    self.statusbar.showMessage('Processing ...')
    img = plt.imread(str(self.ImageFile))
    greyImg = img.mean(axis=2, keepdims=True)/255.0
    greyImg = np.concatenate([greyImg]*3, axis=2)
    vertical_filter = [[-1, -2, -1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1]]
    horizontal_filter = [[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
    n, m, d = greyImg.shape
    edges_img = np.zeros_like(img)
    for row in range(3, n-2):
        for col in range(3, m-2):
            local_pixels = img[row-1:row+2, col-1:col+2, 0]
            vertical_treansformed_pixels = vertical_filter * local_pixels
            vertical_score = vertical_treansformed_pixels.sum() / 8
            horizontal_treansformed_pixels = horizontal_filter*local_pixels
            horizontal_score = horizontal_treansformed_pixels.sum() / 4
            edge_score = (vertical_score ** 2 + horizontal_score ** 2) ** 0.5
            edges_img[row, col] = [edge_score] * 3

    edges_img = edges_img/edges_img.max()
    
    self.NewImageFile = edges_img
    self.img_NewImage.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(edges_img))
    self.statusbar.showMessage('Edges detected and new image generated')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert numpy.ndarray to image format using python image library (PIL)

```
##First import PIL library
from PIL import Image as im
## then convert it to image format
data = im.fromarray(edges_img)
## save the image file as png
data.save('image.png')
##display saved image in Qpixmap
self.img_NewImage.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("image.png"))
```